# Get start Django CMS on Mac 10.10

Tags: python, django, macos, ssl, pip

I was follow the tutorial at https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial/blob/master/Step%201%20-%20Initial%20Setup.md

I manage to install djangocms-installer but every time I try to create a project with

```
  djangocms -p . mysite
```

I go thought prompt questions and the I have

```
 Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

 INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.python.org

 Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django-cms<3.1

 No distributions at all found for django-cms<3.1

 Storing debug log for failure in /Users/user/.pip/pip.log
```

and from my pip.log

```
 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django-cms/: connection error: [Errno 1]    _ssl.c:490: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I found this [pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)
and I tried to  downgrade my pip to 1.2.1

but still I have same error .

Any work around pls?

Comment: can you put pip -V in to the terminal and let us know what version of pip you currently have?

Comment: Solved it out! It was matter just to update my python to 2.7